# Finding most closely matching list in python

Tags: python, list, compare

I am having trouble making an algorithm that will tell me how close of a match one list is to another.

for example, if I have the following lists:

```
a = [-1,2,3]
b = [3,4,4] 
c = [4,-2,-5] 
d = [-3,-4,4]
```

I want to know what array closely resembles my test list.

```
testarray = [3,4,4]
```

This should return list `b`, but my code sometimes returns list `b` and sometimes returns list `d`. Please help me write an algorithm that will compare a list to a bunch of lists and return the closely matched list.

Comment: These are lists; the `array` type in Python is quite a differt type of object.

Comment: What is your distance metric? Sum of the differences? Number of differences? RMSE?

Comment: Providing the code in your current algorithm would help _immensely_.

Comment: To put what @DonaldMiner said in layman's terms: you say "what array closely resembles" but there are multiple ways to define how much a list "closely resembles" another. For example one could say that `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` closely resembles `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` because you just need to remove `1` at the beginning and add `11` at the end of the first list and they are equal. Another person, on the other hand, could say that they are not similar because the elements at the same index are all different.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super messy definition I whipped up. Hope this can help.

```
import copy

#Lists to be tested
a = [-1,2,3]
b = [3,4,4] 
c = [4,-2,-5] 
d = [-3,-4,4] 

#list of lists
lists = [a,b,c,d]
testList = [3,4,4]

def compare(testList,lists):
    #create a list of scores the same length of lists
    scores = []
    for i in range(len(lists)):
        scores.append(0)
    #scores should be [0,0,0,0] now


    for L in lists:
        #create a copy of testList because you will be changing it.
        copyList = copy.deepcopy(testList)
        for val in L:
            #For every value in L, check if it is also in copyList
            if val in copyList:
                #If it is, add to score and delete from copyList.
                #This is so [3,3,3] ends up closer to [3,3,8] than to [3,6,7]
                #This is why we are using a copy of testList
                scores[lists.index(L)]+=1
                del copyList[copyList.index(val)]

print compare(testList,lists)
```